# How can I trim beginning and ending double quotes from a string?

Tags: java, string, trim

I would like to trim a beginning and ending double quote (") from a string.
How can I achieve that in Java? Thanks!

Comment: Is the string already known to have quotes around it, or is checking for quotes part of the problem?

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You can use [`String#replaceAll()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a pattern of `^\"|\"$` for this.

E.g.

```
string = string.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
```

To learn more about regular expressions, have al ook at http://regular-expression.info.

That said, this smells a bit like that you're trying to invent a CSV parser. If so, I'd suggest to look around for existing libraries, such as [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm not building a csv parser. i'm building a facebook app using tinyfbclient and for some reason it provides me the uid of the user with trailing and ending double quotes.

Comment: don't you think it will replaces all occurrences of double quotes with empty string rather then the first and the last.

Comment: @ufk: This isn't a complex regex. You may otherwise want to hassle with a bunch of `String#indexOf()`, `String#substring()`, methods and so on. It's only a little tad faster, but it's much more code. @GK: Uh, did you read/understand the regex or even test it?

Comment: i checked. it does not replace all occurrences of double quotes. only the first and the last.

Comment: sorry BalusC i am not good at Regex, as you have used replaceAll, i had a doubt on that.

Comment: @GK the caret represents the beginning of the searched string, and the dollar sign represents its end.  The backslash here "escapes" the following quote so it's treated as just a character.  So this regex says, replace all occurrences of quote at the start, or quote at the end, with the empty string.  Just as requested.

Comment: @GK: Carl's right. Also, `replace()` methods doesn't accept regex. They accept only a char or a literal string (charsequence). The `replaceAll()` method is the only accepting a regex to match character patterns for replacement.

Comment: How can I replace only pair start/end quotes and leave single quote?

Comment: This doesn't work if the string has a double quote at the beginning only.  It will still match the regex......

Comment: @Marc: I'm not sure how that's a problem considering the question in its current form.

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to remove starting and ending double quotes from a string.

Comment: Here is the regex broken down: `^\"|\"$`. `|` means "or". It will thus match either `^\"` or `\"$`. `^` matches start of string and `$` matches end of string. `^\"` means match a quote at the start of the string and `\"$` matches a quote at the end of the string.

Comment: Regular expression should be /^\"|\"$/ this actually give a compilation error

Comment: @PabloPazos: that can happen if you're confusing Java with JavaScript.

Answer (score 37):

To remove the first character and last character from the string, use:

```
myString = myString.substring(1, myString.length()-1);
```

Comment: This only requires that the quotes should *guaranteed* be present. If there's no guarantee, then you'll need to check it first beforehand.

Comment: @BalusC: Certainly. From my reading of the question, it seems that the string is already known to have quotes around it.

Answer (score 28):

Also with Apache [`StringUtils.strip()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#strip(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

```
 StringUtils.strip(null, *)          = null
 StringUtils.strip("", *)            = ""
 StringUtils.strip("abc", null)      = "abc"
 StringUtils.strip("  abc", null)    = "abc"
 StringUtils.strip("abc  ", null)    = "abc"
 StringUtils.strip(" abc ", null)    = "abc"
 StringUtils.strip("  abcyx", "xyz") = "  abc"
```

So,

```
final String SchrodingersQuotedString = "may or may not be quoted";
StringUtils.strip(SchrodingersQuotedString, "\""); //quoted no more
```

This method works both with quoted and unquoted strings as shown in my example. The only downside is, it will not look for strictly *matched* quotes, only leading and trailing quote characters (ie. no distinction between `"partially` and `"fully"` quoted strings).

Answer (score 27):

## Kotlin

In Kotlin you can use [String.removeSurrounding(delimiter: CharSequence)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/remove-surrounding.html)

E.g.

```
string.removeSurrounding("\"")
```

> Removes the given **delimiter** string from both the start and the end of this string if and only if it starts with and ends with the **delimiter**.
>   Otherwise returns this string unchanged.

The source code looks like this:

```
public fun String.removeSurrounding(delimiter: CharSequence): String = removeSurrounding(delimiter, delimiter)

public fun String.removeSurrounding(prefix: CharSequence, suffix: CharSequence): String {
    if ((length >= prefix.length + suffix.length) && startsWith(prefix) && endsWith(suffix)) {
        return substring(prefix.length, length - suffix.length)
    }
    return this
}
```

Answer (score 21):

If the double quotes only exist at the beginning and the end, a simple code as this would work perfectly:

`string = string.replace("\"", "");`

Comment: Also works in build.gradle

Answer (score 18):

This is the best way I found, to strip double quotes from the beginning and end of a string.

```
someString.replace (/(^")|("$)/g, '')
```

Comment: Maybe include single quotes too replace(/(^\"|\')|(\"|\'$)/g, "");

Answer (score 14):

First, we check to see if the String is doubled quoted, and if so, remove them. You can skip the conditional if in fact you know it's double quoted.

```
if (string.length() >= 2 && string.charAt(0) == '"' && string.charAt(string.length() - 1) == '"')
{
    string = string.substring(1, string.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: This is the most performant answer by orders of magnitude and it even specifies what to do regarding the optional or not presence of the quotes.

Answer (score 12):

Using Guava you can write more elegantly `CharMatcher.is('\"').trimFrom(mystring);`

Comment: is it possible to trim only single character? For example if my string ends with two single quotes still I want only single quote to get trimmed.

Answer (score 7):

I am using something as simple as this :

```
if(str.startsWith("\"") && str.endsWith("\""))
        {
            str = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

To remove one or more double quotes from the start and end of a string in Java, you need to use a regex based solution:

```
String result = input_str.replaceAll("^\"+|\"+$", "");
```

If you need to also remove single quotes:

```
String result = input_str.replaceAll("^[\"']+|[\"']+$", "");
```

**NOTE**: If your string contains `"` inside, this approach might lead to issues (e.g. `"Name": "John"` => `Name": "John`).

See a [Java demo here](https://ideone.com/aGh9hA):

```
String input_str = "\"'some string'\"";
String result = input_str.replaceAll("^[\"']+|[\"']+$", "");
System.out.println(result); // => some string
```

Answer (score 4):

Edited: Just realized that I should specify that this works only if both of them exists. Otherwise the string is not considered quoted. Such scenario appeared for me when working with CSV files.

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.unwrap("\"abc\"", "\"")    = "abc"
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.unwrap("\"abc", "\"")    = "\"abc"
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.unwrap("abc\"", "\"")    = "abc\""
```

Answer (score 3):

The pattern below, when used with `java.util.regex.Matcher`, will match any string between double quotes without affecting occurrences of double quotes inside the string:

```
"[^\"][\\p{Print}]*[^\"]"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("^\"(.*)\"$").matcher(value);
String strUnquoted = value;
if (m.find()) {
    strUnquoted = m.group(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modifying @brcolow's answer a bit

```
if (string != null && string.length() >= 2 && string.startsWith("\"") && string.endsWith("\"") {
    string = string.substring(1, string.length() - 1);
}
```

Comment: I would think that the method argument should be annotated with `@NonNull` and it should probably have something like `Objects.requireNonNull(string)` inside of it because if someone is calling stripQuotes(null) they are probably doing so by mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```
private static String removeQuotesFromStartAndEndOfString(String inputStr) {
    String result = inputStr;
    int firstQuote = inputStr.indexOf('\"');
    int lastQuote = result.lastIndexOf('\"');
    int strLength = inputStr.length();
    if (firstQuote == 0 && lastQuote == strLength - 1) {
        result = result.substring(1, strLength - 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

find indexes of each double quotes and insert an empty string there.

Comment: so it should be first index and the last index of double qoute.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String removeDoubleQuotes(String request) {
    return request.replace("\"", "");
}
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers and an accepted answer. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This was already suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452078/1839439 please do not add another one.

Answer (score -2):

### Groovy

You can subtract a substring from a string using a regular expression in groovy:

```
String unquotedString = theString - ~/^"/ - ~/"$/
```