# removal of double quotes in a sentence

Tags: java, regex, text

I have a text like this:

```
“@joemcelderry91: I've woken up with the flu I think! :( gunna try and
run it off haha!! X” get well soon joey :)
```

I want to get rid of the double quotes in the sentence. After removal it should be like

```
@joemcelderry91: I've woken up with the flu I think! :( gunna try and
run it off haha!! X get well soon joey :)
```

Does anybody have suggestions for removing this so far I have tried this still no luck:

```
.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608665/how-can-i-trim-beginning-and-ending-double-quotes-from-a-string

Comment: .replaceAll('"','') <- that's a double quote treated like a char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you included a different quotes. So Your regex would be,

```
"[“”\"]"
```

Replace it with an empty string.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oE7wM6/8)

OR

If it's a special double quotes then use the below code to remove it from from the string,

```
String str = "“@joemcelderry91: I've woken up with the flu I think! :( gunna try and run it off haha!! X” get well soon joey :)";
String s = str.replaceAll("[“”]", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

Output:

```
@joemcelderry91: I've woken up with the flu I think! :( gunna try and run it off haha!! X get well soon joey :)
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/EE7wBJ)

Comment: Thanks Avinash for spotting my problem it is a special double quote which I was not able to get rid of.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `replaceAll()` does nothing to the string, because strings are immutable. Instead, `replaceAll()` *returns* the modified string, so *assign* the return value:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"", "");
```

Also... don't use regex!!! Neither your search term nor your replacement need regex, so use the non-regex version of replace:

```
str = str.replace("\"", "");
```

Note that despite its name not having "all" in it, `replace()` still replaces all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you are getting? This works for me:

`String str = "@joemcelderry91: I've woken up with the flu I think! :( gunna try and run it off haha!! X\" get well soon joey :)";

        System.out.println(str.replaceAll("\"", ""));`

Gave me output:

@joemcelderry91: I've woken up with the flu I think! :( gunna try and run it off haha!! X get well soon joey :)