# Set http link for text cell in Google Sheets Java Api

Tags: java, google-sheets-api

I want to insert in Google sheets cell text with hyperlink:

[image]

I tried this Java code:

```
values.add(new CellData()
                .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
                    .setStringValue(get.getTitle())).setHyperlink(get.getUrl())
```

But I get only text without hyperlink.
How I can implement this?

Comment: What is the error that you are encountering? Anyway, as a workaround, why don't you try the idea from this SO Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527719/how-to-add-hyperlink-in-jlabel? Play with it until you get a working link. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: I don't get any exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/CellData.html#setHyperlink(java.lang.String))

> A hyperlink this cell points to, if any. This field is read-only. (To set it, use a `=HYPERLINK` formula in the userEnteredValue.formulaValue field.)

You can't set multiple properties for an ExtendedValue object it only accepts single property to set. All properties point a value for Cell but only difference is those setters determines the type of cell value (bool, string, formula, number, error), so you can't set multiple value for Single Cell thats why you get the error( *(oneof), oneof field 'value' is already set* ).

Here is the new code, you can add hyperlink like this:

```java
values.add(
    new CellData()
        .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
        .setFormulaValue("=HYPERLINK(\"http://stackoverflow.com\",\"SO label\")")
);
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov added the snippet it should work like this.

Comment: In general it's working wit this code: `.setFormulaValue("=HYPERLINK(\"" + get.getUrl() + "\",\"" + get.getTitle() + "\")"))` but I have a issue when I have " " into the title. Is there any solution? Probably to parse the title first?

Comment: @PeterPenzov from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608682) get.setTitle(get.getTitle().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "")); will solve your problem

Comment: @PeterPenzov the solution for quotes in HYPERLINK   `replaceAll("\"", "\"\""); `

Comment: I sterted this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230873/set-custom-column-width-size-in-google-sheets Can you give some advice, please?