# Set custom column width size in google sheets

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using this Java code to generate Google sheets data from Java application.

```java
List < RowData > rowDataValues = new ArrayList < > ();

List < CellData > headerValues = new ArrayList < > ();
headerValues.add(new CellData().setNote("ID")
    .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
        .setStringValue("#")).setUserEnteredFormat(myFormat));
.setStringValue("Environment")).setUserEnteredFormat(myFormat));

.........

headerValues.add(new CellData()
    .setUserEnteredValue(new ExtendedValue()
        .setStringValue("Name")).setUserEnteredFormat(myFormat));
RowData setHeaderValues = new RowData();
setHeaderValues.setValues(headerValues);
rowDataValues.add(setHeaderValues);

requests.add(new Request()
    .setUpdateCells(new UpdateCellsRequest()
        .setStart(new GridCoordinate()
            .setSheetId(randomSheetId)
            .setRowIndex(0)
            .setColumnIndex(0))
        .setRows(rowDataValues)
        .setFields("*")));

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest body = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(requests);

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId, body).execute();
```

How I can set custom width for each column?

Update:

This is what i've tried so far :

```java
new UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest().setRange(
        new DimensionRange()
        .setDimension("COLUMNS")
        .setStartIndex(0).setEndIndex(1)
    )
    .setProperties(new DimensionProperties().setPixelSize(400)).setFields("pixelSize"));
```

Comment: What have you done so far with UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't found a solution how to implement it.

Comment: Currently I don't have access to my environment, can you link the code snippet that i have sent you before ?

Comment: did you add this one to the request list with wrapping Request  object ? ( new Request().setUpdateDimensionProperties( new UpdateDimensionProp...

Comment: I update the code that I have tested. This is the exact part which I don't know how to implement. Can you give me some code snippet where I need to set setUpdateDimensionProperties into my code?

Comment: You just need to add request to your requests array; requests.add(new Request().setUpdateDimensionProperties( new UpdateDimensionProp... and the rest

Comment: Can you make it as a official answer so that I can vote it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create [UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest.html). In your case you can use this sample code, which increases the size of first column `(startIndex = 0, endIndex = 1)` .

```java
requests.add(new Request().setUpdateDimensionProperties(
    new UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest()
    .setRange(
        new DimensionRange()
        .setSheetId(randomSheetId)
        .setDimension("COLUMNS")
        .setStartIndex(0)
        .setEndIndex(1)
)
.setProperties(new DimensionProperties().setPixelSize(400)).setFields("pixelSize"))));
```

In here i used `setDimension("COLUMNS")` to change column(s) width, it is possible to change row(s) height by using `setDimension("ROWS")`.

---

*Additional problem from* [@PeterPenzov 's  comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45230873/set-custom-column-width-size-in-google-sheets#comment77436817_45235313) :

> I get "Invalid [requests.updateDimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/model/UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest.html): No grid with id: 0",

You'll get this error when your sheetId is not set properly.

From API v4 documentation [SheetId](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#sheet_id) is ;

> Individual sheets in a spreadsheet have titles (which must be unique) and IDs. The sheetId is used frequently in the Sheets API to specify which sheet is being read or updated

So you need to set `sheetId` of `DimensionRange` Object. In your case you need to use your `sheetId` as `randomSheetId`(i've updated the code above).

```java
Spreadsheet spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId).execute();
spreadsheet.getSheets().stream()
                       .map(s->s.getProperties().getSheetId())
                       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I get "Invalid requests[1].updateDimensionProperties: No grid with id: 0",

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look into [dev documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn):

```js
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateDimensionProperties": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
          "startIndex": 0,
          "endIndex": 1
        },
        "properties": {
          "pixelSize": 160
        },
        "fields": "pixelSize"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Request body from the example for column width could be translated into the next Java code:

```
public void updateFirstColumnWidth(Sheets sheetService, String sheetId) throws IOException {
    final Spreadsheet spreadsheet = sheetService.spreadsheets()
        .get(sheetId)
        .execute();
    final var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
    final var sheet = sheets.get(0); // get your specific sheet
    final int sheetUuid = sheet.getProperties().getSheetId();
    final var batchRequest = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
    List<Request> requests = List.of(getColumnWidthRequest(sheetUuid, 160));
    batchRequest.setRequests(requests);
    final BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = sheetService.spreadsheets()
        .batchUpdate(sheetId, batchRequest)
        .execute();
}

private Request getColumnWidthRequest(int sheetUuid, int width) {
    return new Request()
        .setUpdateDimensionProperties(
            new UpdateDimensionPropertiesRequest()
                .setRange(
                    new DimensionRange()
                        .setSheetId(sheetUuid)
                        .setDimension("COLUMNS")
                        .setStartIndex(0)
                        .setEndIndex(1)
                )
                .setProperties(new DimensionProperties().setPixelSize(width))
                .setFields("pixelSize")
        );
}
```