# Splitting a text file at regular expressions and creating an array

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I need some help with a splitting a text file with java. I have a text file with around 2000 words, the text file is in the format as follows -

```
"A", "HELLO", "RANDOM", "WORD"... etc
```

My goal is to put these words into a string array. Using the scanner class I'm taking the text and creating a string, then trying to split and add to an array as follows.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

while(input.hasNext()){

   String temp = input.next();

   String[] wordArray = temp.split(",");
}
```

After added to the array, when I want to use or print each element, they are stored with the "" surrounding them. Instead of printing

```
A
HELLO
RANDOM
```

… etc they are printing

```
"A"
"HELLO"
"RANDOM"
```

So my question is how can I get rid of these regular expressions and split the text at each word so I'm left with no regular expressions?

Many Thanks

Comment: reformat the question for better reading

Comment: Hope this helps..https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608682/10416835

Comment: Great, thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this to replace all occurrences of " with an empty string.

```
wordArray[i].replaceAll("/"", "");
```

Perform this in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(FILE_PATH), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        while(input.hasNext()){
            String temp = input.next();
            Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\"(.*)\"").matcher(temp);
            while (m.find()) {
                allMatches.add(m.group(1));
            }
        }
        allMatches.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in your case, when you have all values like this `"A", "HELLO", "RANDOM", "WORD"... etc`, where every value have delimiter `", "`, you can use this  `temp.split("\", \"");` and you don't need to use loop.